# Is there any way to create local form with hidden login id and password in ASP application?

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, asp.net-core

Hi Is there any way to create local form with hidden login id and password in ASP ?

https://ipindiaonline.gov.in/epatentfiling/OnlineFiling/OnlineFormFiling

i just creating simple form code with hidden value for user id and passowrd but the code dint work.. any suggestion?

```
<form ="post" action="https://ipindiaonline.gov.in/epatentfiling/user/frmloginNew1.aspx" id="Form1" autocomplete="off" target="_blank">
   <input name="TBUserName" type="hidden" id="TBUserName" value="USERID">
   <br><br>
   <input name="TBPassword" type="hidden" id="TBPassword" value="PASSWORD">
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="LnkSubmitLogin" value="Login" id="LnkSubmitLogin">
</form>
```

-------------UPDATE------------------

the site i.e., ipindiaonline[.]gov[.]in using the following code in login page

[image]

Comment: The way you are doing it the "TBUserName" and "TBPassword" fields should not be displayed on the page. Can you elaborate what specifically it not working for you?

Comment: How does the shared link related to your issue not clear. What do you want to achieve with hidden Id and password? Do you want to submit hidden Id and password to your shared link?

Comment: @Meryovi I would like to pass the "TBUserName" and "TBPassword" details in hidden to directly login to that website mentioned above (i.e., ipindiaonline[.]gov[.]in) and but I came to know that it uses asp application so I could log in with the code I mentioned above.

Comment: @md-farid-uddin-kiron  i would like to create a local form code to log in to that website (i.e., ipindiaonline[.]gov[.]in).. i couldn't do it as its uses asp.net

Comment: If you create local form how could you send request? Does that end point accept request from outside?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you're looking to hide the user's password when they're typing it in, so another nearby user cannot see it.

If that's the case, you'll want to change the `type` attribute on your `input` elements to `password`.

You can see examples of this (and other input types) [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

Comment: Yes you are right but the website I am trying to pass this hidden information to ipindiaonline[.]gov[.]in but they are using asp.net so I couldn't use this code to pass these information